# How Do I Clear Any Cells That Have Certain Text Strings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is receiving Google Form responses. I'd like to run something on formSubmit() that combs through the entire form response sheet, and clears any cells that have certain values in the text string.

The code I have so far is below. It run, but doesn't clear the cells out.

```
function badData() {
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[spreadsheetstring]");
    var content = file.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    return content.value ? (listBadWords(content.value) !== -1 ? content.range.clearContent() : null) : null;
}

function listBadWords(word) {
    var listEN = [
        'none', 'n/a', 'n.a'
    ];
    return listEN.indexOf(word);
}
```

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update:**
With @Liora's help, the following works great:

```
function badMMData() {
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[spreadsheetstring]");
    var content = file.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var numRows = content.getLastRow();
    var numCols = content.getLastColumn();
    var range = content.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols);
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
            var currentValue = range.getCell(i, j).getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
            if (listBadWords(currentValue) !== -1)
                range.getCell(i, j).clear();
        }
    }
}

function listBadWords(word) {
    var listEN = [
        'none', 'n/a', 'n.a', 'na'
    ];
    return listEN.indexOf(word);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `content.value` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function clear works on a precise range, so you need to loop on all the ranges of the spreadsheet. Something like:

```
var numRows = content.getLastRow();
var numCols = content.getLastColumns();
var range = content.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols);
for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
       var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
       if(listBadWords(currentValue) !== -1)
           range.getCell(i,j).clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I just slightly modified to make it case insensitive, and it works great now. I've edited my OP with the solution for anyone else that might need it. : )